# Did Erasmus use Codex Basilensis for his Novum Instrumentum omne?

Tags: bible, new-testament, greek

I am looking for a definitive answer to whether or not Erasmus used Codex Basilensis 'A. N. III. 12 (07 on the list Gregory-Aland) — the four Gospels in Greek in uncial letters; 8th century' in his Novum Instrumentum omne?

Comment: Which Codex Basilensis - there are at least seven documents ranging in date from the 8th to 15th century with this general title.

Comment: Which Codex Basilensis? In that case, any of them.

Comment: The short answer is almost certainly yes.  He used Codex Basilensis A. N. IV. 2 (1 on the list Gregory-Aland) — New Testament (except Apocalypse) in Greek in minuscule letters; 12th century; and Codex Basiliensis A. N. IV. 1 (2 on the list Gregory-Aland) — the four Gospels in Greek in minuscule letters; 11th/12th century; plus a few others

Comment: He [probably also used Codex Basilensis A. N. IV. 4 (2815 on the list Gregory-Aland) — Acts of the Apostles and Pauline epistles in Greek in minuscule letters; 12th century as well.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novum_Instrumentum_omne

Comment: Perhaps the claims against him using it was with respect to Codex Basilensis A. N. III. 12 (07 on the list Gregory-Aland) — the four Gospels in Greek in uncial letters; 8th century; ?

Comment: Novum Instrumentum Omne was a ground-breaking effort, published is a great hurry to get a publishing scoop (it worked).  The main criticism was the very poor and sloppy editing - it had hundreds of errors and several more editions were published to fix them.  It also included a number of verses not found in the Greek but only in the Latin Vulgate.  However, it had the effect of galvanising Tyndale and Luther, among others, to translate the Bible into the common tongue and thus a great slew of fresh translations appeared.